# Call a $index created in a function of another file php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call a variable called $index that count the number of a foreach iteration that is inside a function. 
In this same function, i call another function that needs to get this $index value at the end of the foreach.

```
       <?php

$index = 0;

function edit_profile_form() {

    global $index;
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $data = get_user_meta ($current_user_id);

    if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
        delete_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['button1'])) {
        save_extra_profile_fields($current_user_id, $index);
    };

    $experiences = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences', true);

?>

[...SOME CODE HERE...]
```

Next in the file (but always in the function), i call this :

```
if (!empty($experiences)) {
        foreach ($experiences as $key) {
        ?>
            <div class="past_experience">
                <div class="experience_header">
                    <div>
                        <label for="team">Nom de l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="team" name="team_<?= $index ?>" value="<?= $key['new_experience_team'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="role">Rôle dans l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="role" name="role_<?= $index ?>" value="<?= $key['new_experience_role'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="experience_textarea">
                    <label for="description">Description du rôle</label>
                    <textarea class="description" name="description_<?= $index ?>"><?= $key['new_experience_description']; ?></textarea>

                    <label for="palmares">Palmarés avec l'équipe</label>
                    <textarea class="palmares" name="palmares_<?= $index ?>"><?= $key['new_experience_palmares']; ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>  
        <?php
        $index++;
        } 

    } else {
    ?>
    <div><p>Vous n'avez encore rentré aucune expérience</p></div>
```

And here is now the function called at the beginnig of the file but placed in another file :

```
function save_extra_profile_fields($user_id, $index) {

if (!empty($_POST['experiences'])) {
    $experiences[] = $_POST['experiences'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++) {
        $experience_{$i}['new_experience_team'] = $_POST["team_{$i}"];
        $experience_{$i}['new_experience_role'] = $_POST["role_{$i}"];
        $experience_{$i}['new_experience_description'] = $_POST["description_{$i}"];
        $experience_{$i}['new_experience_palmares'] = $_POST["palmares_{$i}"];
        $experiences[] = $experience_{$i};
    }
    update_usermeta($user_id, 'experiences', $experiences);
}
```

}

It's not working because in this function, $index is not defined in fact.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

## Try

Change `function edit_profile_form()`

to

`function edit_profile_form() use ($index)`

Then remove the global keyword inside.

## Global way

To have it otherwise available for all functions you could use `$GLOBALS['index']` instead everywhere instead of `$index`.

Comment: I made it like this but have an "unexpected use", is it normal ?

Comment: Yup the global version doesn't work and the version with the "use" gives me the error message ^^

Comment: Did you try the global way, too?

Comment: Yep, changed it in the main file and in the function one. Have i got to remove/add something in this case ?

Comment: Then you should not use $index anywhere. You may use something different like `$GLOBALS['special_index']`. Also define it at the very first entry point of your PHP script like $GLOBALS['special_index'] = 0;

Comment: Okay i'll try this ! Thanks ;)